# iMessage on iPad with 2 iPhone numbers

Tags: ipad, messages, ios

Is it possible to use two different iPhone numbers for receiving iMessages on my iPad?

Comment: I suppose in theory it would be, but could you give a little more background as to why you want to do that. That might help us figure out if it will work for you.

Comment: I'm going to buy a second iPhone and I would like to receive iMessages send to my iPhones (the one I already have and the new one) on my iPad.

Comment: That's not what you have been asking above (at least not directly). Just edit the question to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iPad would only be able to receive iMessages through an email account. Normally it will default to your Apple ID, however you can add multiple email accounts to receive messages on through iMessage through Settings > Messages > Send&Receive > Add Another Email.

Use the same AppleID/email account(s) for receiving messages on both phones and you will receive all iMessages sent to those accounts.

Although the iPad does not have the option of receiving iMessages from specific phone numbers, I have tested sending a message from someone else's iMessage (OsX Mountain Lion) directly to my phone number and it showed up both on my iPad as well as on my iPhone. Both are on iOS 6.

Comment: As of iOS 6, this is inaccurate. An iPad can send and receive iMessages from the phone number of an iPhone, if both are running iOS 6, and have iMessages enabled on the same Apple ID.

Comment: robmathers: Both my iPhone and my iPad are running iOS 6. The iPad, as I've stated above will in fact receive the iMessage sent to the phone number, however the iPad does not have the option in Settings > Messages > Send & Receive to set a specific phone number, just emails.

Comment: That's a bug then. Mine (and others I've tested) definitely has the option to send from a phone number. You should try disabling then re-enabling iMessage on your iPad, which can fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but after signing out of imessage on my ipad and disabling imessage on my ipad, when i reenabled imessage on my ipad, the option to use my phone number appeared.